# Need to use yatra.com API in my website

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, api

asalamualikum , I need to used yatra.com api on my website which is an asp.net website.I have got a word document from yatra(air integration document). Yatra api is xml based , air integration document shows format of xml requests and responses but I haven't used xml in webservices and have no idea but I have concept of xml but have used xml only to read and write files on local system.Now I have a problem I dont know how to use xml in webservices and how to recieve response from api and display it on my page or sent request to api..If any one can help me I will be very thankful to him......If you could give me ne url or a video where user have used some api(xml based) for integration. Help will be strongly appreciated.If anyone can give me sample code for below request and resonse.

Sample request to yatra api:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
<OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ EchoToken="0" SequenceNmbr="0" TransactionIdentifier="0" AvailableFlightsOnly="" DirectFlightsOnly="" xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
            <POS xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
                <Source AgentSine="" PseudoCityCode="NPCK" TerminalID="1">
                    <RequestorID ID="AFFILIATE"/>
                </Source>
                <YatraRequests>
                    <YatraRequest AffiliateID="EASTBOUND"/>
                </YatraRequests>
            </POS>
            <TravelerInfoSummary>
                <AirTravelerAvail>
                    <PassengerTypeQuantity Code="ADT" Quantity="1"/>
                    <PassengerTypeQuantity Code="CHD" Quantity="1"/>
                    <PassengerTypeQuantity Code="INF" Quantity="1"/>
                </AirTravelerAvail>
            </TravelerInfoSummary>
            <SpecificFlightInfo>
                <Airline Code=""/>
            </SpecificFlightInfo>
            <OriginDestinationInformation>
                <DepartureDateTime>2011-09-11T00:00:00</DepartureDateTime>
                <OriginLocation CodeContext="IATA" LocationCode="DEL">DEL</OriginLocation>
                <DestinationLocation CodeContext="IATA" LocationCode="BOM">BOM</DestinationLocation>
            </OriginDestinationInformation>
            <TravelPreferences>
                <VendorPref Code="SG"/>
                <VendorPref Code="DN"/>
                <CabinPref Cabin=""/>
            </TravelPreferences>
        </OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Sample Response from yatra api

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS Version="2.001" xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
            <PricedItineraries>
                <PricedItinerary CompositeFlightNumber="S2101" CountCompositeFlightNumber="1" OriginDestinationRPH="0" SequenceNumber="1" SupplierSystem="Amadeus">
                    <AirItinerary SupplierSystem="Amadeus">
                        <OriginDestinationOptions>
                            <OriginDestinationOption Duration="01:55:00" FromCache="true" SupplierSystem="Amadeus">
                                <FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="2007-11-11T08:55:00" DepartureDateTime="2007-11-11T07:00:00" E_TicketEligibility="Eligible" FlightNumber="101" RPH="1" ResBookDesigCode="O">
                                    <BookingClassAvail RPH="1" ResBookDesigCode="O" ResBookDesigQuantity="4"/>
                                    <DepartureAirport LocationCode="DEL"/>
                                    <ArrivalAirport LocationCode="BOM"/>
                                    <Equipment AirEquipType="737"/>
                                    <MarketingAirline Code="S2"/>
                                </FlightSegment>
       <FormData>
                <FareInformationIDs>
                <FareInformationID BaseFare="1825" Code="" FareCode="UGOSAVE" FareID="0" PTCID="1" Quantity="">0</FareInformationID>
            </FareInformationIDs>
      </FormData>                            
</OriginDestinationOption>
                        </OriginDestinationOptions>
                    </AirItinerary>
                    <AirItineraryPricingInfo>
                        <ItinTotalFare>
                            <BaseFare Amount="1875" CurrencyCode="INR"/>
                            <Taxes>
                                <Tax Amount="1575" CurrencyCode="INR" TaxCode="TTL"/>
                            </Taxes>
                            <TotalFare Amount="3461.63" CurrencyCode="INR"/>
                            <ServiceTax Amount="11.63" Currency="INR" Description="Service Tax" ServiceTaxCode="ST" ServiceTaxRate="0.0062"/>
                        </ItinTotalFare>
                        <PTC_FareBreakdowns>
                            <PTC_FareBreakdown>
                                <PassengerTypeQuantity Code="ADT" Quantity="1"/>
                                <FareBasisCodes>
                                    <FareBasisCode>OSASAS</FareBasisCode>
                                </FareBasisCodes>
                                <PassengerFare>
                                    <BaseFare Amount="1875" CurrencyCode="INR"/>
                                    <Taxes>
                                        <Tax Amount="1575" CurrencyCode="INR" TaxCode="TTL"/>
                                    </Taxes>
                                    <TotalFare Amount="3450" CurrencyCode="INR"/>
                                </PassengerFare>
                            </PTC_FareBreakdown>
                        </PTC_FareBreakdowns>
                        <FareInfos>
                            <FareInfo>
                                <FareReference>OSASAS</FareReference>
                                <FilingAirline Code="ZZ"/>
                                <DepartureAirport LocationCode="DEL"/>
                                <ArrivalAirport LocationCode="BOM"/>
                            </FareInfo>
                        </FareInfos>
                    </AirItineraryPricingInfo>
                    <TicketingInfo DeliveryMethod="EMAIL" TicketTimeLimit="" TicketType="eTicket" TicketingStatus="" eTicketNumber="">
                        <TicketAdvisory Language="English"/>
                    </TicketingInfo>
                </PricedItinerary>
            </PricedItineraries>
        </OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

You no need to worry about creating the xml or consuming the xml, if you are using C sharp side use WCF or any tool to create client by using Yatra.com wsdl.
Now treat evrthing as object oriented it will be responsibility of your C sharp client stubs to generate XML. you just need to map the values in stubs.